# Validate XML with required and optional attribute values

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd, dtd

I have a XML file with this structure:

```
<add>
<doc>
<field name="url">an Url</field>
<field name="title">a title</field>
<field name="author">an author</field>
</doc>
[[<doc>...</doc>][<doc>..</doc>]]
</add>
```

So in every 'doc' there is the same element 'field' with the same attribute 'name' but with different possible values: "url", "title", "author".

I need to validate my file so that for every 'doc' the attribute value "url" is required, but at the same time the attribute values "title" and "author" are optional. The problem is that they all belongs to the same attribute 'name'.

Is there a way to do this in DTD or XML Schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot or will not redesign your XML to exploit the strengths of XML's design, you can probably get some kind of validation to work using assertions in XSD 1.1.

But the simplest approach would be to redesign your XML:

```
<add>
<doc>
<url>an Url</url>
<title>a title</title>
<author>an author</author>
</doc>
[[<doc>...</doc>][<doc>..</doc>]]
</add>
```

Now the constraints you describe are trivial to enforce in either DTDs or XSDs.

Like most technologies, XML tools work better if you work with them instead of fighting them.

Comment: you are right, but that is the XML format required by the program I have to use (Solr: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#The_Update_Schema ), so I think the only thing I can do is to create a customized parser to validate that file. Thank you

Comment: One simple way to deal with external data sources or data sinks that insist on badly designed XML is to create a simple lossless conversion between the external XML format and a more tractable XML format you can use (and validate) internally.  So:  writing a custom validator is *one* thing you can do, but *not* the only thing you can do.